# Spring equivalent of EJB Singleton to maintain the state

Tags: java, spring, thread-safety, singleton, ejb

Currently I'm working on a JSF2 + Spring application. And I need to have one component, which I would be able to autowire when needed and read/write the state (safely) from/to it.

In EJB I would do it as follows:

```
@Singleton
@ConcurrencyManagement(ConcurrencyManagementType.CONTAINER)
public class LocaleManager {

  private String currentLanguage;

  @Lock(LockType.READ)
  public String getCurrentLanguage() {
    return currentLanguage;
  }

  @Lock(LockType.WRITE)
  public void setCurrentLanguage(String currentLanguage) {
    this.currentLanguage  = currentLanguage;
  }

}
```

How can I achieve this in Spring? Thanks!

**EDIT:** One important thing is that application has multiple Maven modules and I need this in "core" module which doesn't depend on spring-web. I need the language information in DTO assemblers, where I would like to use only string values relevant to the current locale set in JSF. Entity has a set of translations for various languages (each DB table has own translation table). In the corresponding DTO I would like to have just e.g. "String description", instead of "Set`<ItemTranslation>` description".

Answer (score -1):

In Spring the `scope` of the bean says how the instances are created. I suggest you to check out the following tutorial:

http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-bean-scopes-examples/